# How to apply hover on contact form 7 button

Tags: css, contact-form-7

[image: Hover-image]

---

I need contact form7 `submit` button hover design with side arrow like below image how to do that?

Here is my  css

```
[submit "submit class:test] .wpcf7 input[type="submit"],
 .wpcf7 input[type="button"] {
  background-color: #C2E8F5;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
}
/* this is contact form 7 code*/

.et_pb_button:after,
.et_pb_button:before {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -1em;
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: none;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: none;
  line-height: 1em;
  text-transform: none;
  content: "\35";
}
```

Comment: please add html and css what you have tried?

Comment: Add your code...

Comment: [submit "submit class:test]
.wpcf7 input[type="submit"], .wpcf7 input[type="button"] {
    background-color: #C2E8F5;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
}
// this is contact form 7 code
.et_pb_button:after, .et_pb_button:before {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -1em;
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: none;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: none;
    line-height: 1em;
    text-transform: none;
    content: "\35";
  
}

Answer (score 0):

use fa icon plugin, jquery and css to achieve this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".btn").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".hover-icon").addClass("fa-chevron-right");
  });
   $(".btn").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".hover-icon").removeClass("fa-chevron-right");
  });
});
```

```css
.btn {
  background-color: blue;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius:5px;
}


/* Darker background on mouse-over */
.btn:hover {
  background-color:#fff;
  color:#00f;
  border:1px solid #00f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<button class="btn">Apply Here <i class="fa hover-icon"></i> </button>
```